# How to make timer stop on click Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a timer within javascript. I want the timer to stop on click but it won't. I have two parameters: "start" and "stop". I want my program to restart the timer if the start button is clicked while the timer is already going and to stop when the stop button is clicked.

```
function timer(start, stop) {
let count;
if (start) {
    let count = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }, 1000);
}
if (stop) {
    count = count;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `clearInterval` to stop the timer when it's running, and then set it again if they click when it's not running.  Something like this:

```js
var timer;
var running = false;
var elapsed = 0;
var div = document.getElementById('time');
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (running) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        running = false;
    } else {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            elapsed++;
            div.textContent = elapsed;
            }, 1000);
        running = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<div id="time"/>
```